# How can I output the contents of multiple files, preceded by their filename?

Tags: find, cat

I'm looking for a command like

```
find -name "*clang*" -exec cat {} \;
```

or

```
cat $(find -name "*clang*")
```

but giving me the file's path before each file's contents.

Answer (score 1):

This has the advantage of spawning only one awk per run:

```
find . -type f -name '*clang*' -exec awk 'FNR==1{print FILENAME}1' {} +
```

Meaning of awk body:

- `FNR==1{print FILENAME}`: For the first line of each file found, print its path.
- `1`: For each line, print it.

Answer (score 0):

I found out that this is actually simpler than I thought:

```
find -name "*clang*" -print -exec cat {} \;
```

Comment: Although that would still try to run `cat` on any matching _directories_ and other non-regular files. Also, it would require GNU `find` as other `find` implementations don't use the current directory by default if a search path isn't given.

Comment: For the first one, that's fine. For the second, a dot after find would solve that, right?

Comment: Yes. And to only care about regular files, use `-type f`.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following command:

```
find / -name "*clang*" -exec basename {} \; -exec cat {} \;
```